# Submit a form to DJANGO from Phonegap Application using JAVAScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, cordova

I have written a Phonegap application and I would like to know how can I submit a form to Django using Javascript or Jquery. I have already implemented a JSON API using Tastypie.

Can anybody provide me with some ideas, or any guidance on how to implement such a function?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to do ajax call to tastypie api url in the below format.

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url:  site_url+'api/v2/user/login/',
      data: '{"username": "developer", "password":"imagine2"}',
      processData: false,
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log('jquery worked');
                //results=JSON.stringify(response);
                setCookie( "sessionid", response.sessionid);
                setCookie( "app_version", response.app_version);
                window.location.href = 'home/'; 
                $('#overlay').hide();
      },
      error: function (res) {   
        msg = (res.responseText) ? res.responseText : res.statusText;
        console.log(msg+",res.status="+res.status);
        alert(msg);

      },
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    });
```

Also you need to enable cross domain.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. Since you are using an API with tastypie I would suggest not submitting the form itself, but extracting the form data before submitting the form with JavaScript. On submit you pass the data you want to submit in the request body to your API endpoint.

As an example you could have an api endpoint for blog entries, lets say its `http://example.com/api/v1/entry`. Considering your API allows cross-domain requests (e.g. via CORS) you could do something simple as this to "submit" your form (e.g. creating a new entry):

```
$('#myForm #mySubmitButton').click(function() {
    $.post('http://example.com/api/v1/entry', $('#myForm').serialize(), function(data) {
        // deal with the response data
    }
});
```

I am not sure tastypie supports this kind of data structure. A little longer version of this could be to do something like this (here I am sure tastypie does support it), which submits the data as a JSON:

```
$('#myForm #mySubmitButton').click(function() {
    var data = {'title': $('#myForm #titleInput').val(), 'description': $('#myForm #descriptionInput').val()};
    $.post('http://example.com/api/v1/entry', data, function(data) {
        // deal with the response data
    }
});
```

This examples do not deal with form validation, error handling etc.. You could have look into [tastypie validation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validation.html) for more details and potentially also add frontend specific validation with HTML5. I would also suggest you to use a more sophisticated JavaScript framework like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) for single page apps like a PhoneGap app. JQuery will bloat your app soon, when it grows.